# iOS FSVerticalTabBarController glitchy when selecting tabBar items

Tags: ios, select, touch, tabbar

I'm currently using the 'FSVerticalTabBarController' which takes a standard `TabBarController` and places it on the left side vertically. My problem with it is that whenever I select a `TabBarItem` and drag (While holding my finger down) it immediately deselects the Item. It only works if you press the `TabBarItem` WITHOUT dragging your finger at all.

I want it to select that `TabBarItem` when the user lifts his/her finger inside the region of the Item or something similar. How do I achieve this?

[FSVerticalTabBarController:](https://github.com/futuresimple/FSVerticalTabBarController)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Still trying to figure out what is causing it. But weird enough it works well on his sample project.

Comment: For me, this issue was solved in iOS 7 automatically. Some deprecations came along but were easily fixed.

Comment: well i notice its working fine on the device but not on the simulator. lol

Comment: Yeah, seems to behave pretty weird sometimes.. Glad it worked out on the device though :)